# Play Side Stick (SS) on Electric Drums

Tags: technique, drums

I currently have a electric drum set

[image]

I am wondering if its possible or is there any way to play the [Side Stick technique](http://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCoQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DP5V7XVbaf2Y&ei=07T4UpivLoWPrQejmIHIBg&usg=AFQjCNF5p30i22M8cEJJbzrBhWNED53zqg&bvm=bv.60983673,d.bmk) which is meant for an acoustic drum set on a electric drum set

Comment: I'm guessing the technique won't work -- but of course you can get the sound itself by loading a sidestick sound into whatever pad/zone you like.

Answer (score 5):

for electronic kits, the manufacturers generally concentrate on providing sensors for the drum skin, not so much the rim of the drum.

There are exceptions though. I have a Roland TD8 kit, the snare of which which has an extra sensor around the rim. It can be set separately from the drum skin, so that hitting the rim provides either side-stick, more snare (or any sound you like), or a rimshot (snare skin and rim hit at same time - it can work out when that happens).

To be honest all the side-stick "simulation" does is play a sidestick sound when you hit the rim. It doesn't to anything more versatile.

The TD8 is a bit old now (2004?) and there's every chance more modern kits will have this, but it depends what you buy. Basically you need a pad with a sensor around the rim, and the electronic brain where you program the sounds needs to be able to work out what you're hitting and what you want to happen. It's a common thing to want to do, so I'd think it's covered quite well nowadays.

The alternative is that most (all? ) electronic will have a side-stick sound which you can allocate to a pad, so you can do this but have to lose a dedicated pad to it.